# White space below background image

Tags: html, css

There's a white bar appearing below my image when i minimize the window, when its not minimize there's no white space. I've checked my background have no white spaces below it. The actual resolution of the picture is 1920x1080.

I believe its the background shrinking that's causing the problem. I might be wrong, but if i'm correct, how do i prevent the background from shrinking below its resolution?

I've tried background-size: cover/contain.

```
html, body{height: 100%;}
```

This is my current code:

```
`html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
    background: url(test2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe because your html page is static. 
To enable "dynamic" mode you need to add this line in the head:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: I found the source of the problem, i was trying to learn to how make a responsive dropdown navigation bar and found a video and followed it.  

i was using the "height: 100vh" instead of "height: calc(100vh - 50px)" and so when the navigation bar collapses it creates a vertical scroll bar on the right side of the webpage and when the background resizes it leaves a blank space when you scroll to the bottom. But changing the code to the second one removes the scroll bar. But i don't quite understand how it works. Can you explain it to me? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't really understand it too but I think it is because the first value ( 100vh ) depends on the actual device screen size but the second value ( 50px ) is fixed so it is 50 px on every device. I hope I didn't said anything stupid

Comment: According to w3schools: " vh: Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport "

Comment: hmm.. hopefully someone comes and explain it to both of us. Thanks for the help tho. Appreciate it.